How to transfer a lot of photos to another iphone including edit history?
Is there a way to transfer a lot of photos (from the Photo Library AKA Photos app) from one iPhone to another including edits?
AirDrop does transfer the edit history, but transferring a lot (about 4000, including some videos) of photos over AirDrop does not work. After the Preparing and Downloading steps it shows:
Unable to Share
There was an error while preparing to
share. Please try again later.

Most other tools do not preserve the edits. (at least none that I tried, for example SHAREit)
PS: Moving photos to another iCloud account and device, with full resolution, edit history, everything is similar, but it suggests AirDrop which is not usable for my case.

Maybe Airdrop has a built-in limit to the number of files, or one of the files is somehow damaged? Dunno, just spitballin' here. Also maybe those 3rd party iOS backup utilities (iMazing and iExplore, I think...) can help with this.

So to be clear, the destination phone is not participating in the same iCloud Photo Library?

@MarcWilson No. Both use the same iCloud account, but no Photos, as they exceed the iCloud size.

So the only place the photos (and the edits) are, is on the first phone.  I understand.
